# Retrieving num of rows in MySQLI

Tags: php, object, mysqli

I am trying to get the number of rows in my query but it keeps giving me this error

> Trying to get property of non-object on line 15.

```
<?php require_once("./includes/Utilities.php") ;?>
<?php require_once("./includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
        $conf_pass = trim($_POST['conf_password']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        require_once('./includes/CheckPassword.php');
        $check_pwd = new Db_CheckPassword($password);
        $check_pwd =$check_pwd->check();
        require_once('./includes/CheckUsername.php');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = {$username}";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $numRows = $result->num_rows;
    }
?>
```

This is specifically line 15

```
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
```

Why is it returning an error?

Comment: While you are using MySQLi, you're not using prepared statements! which leads to the same type of SQL injection vulnerability introduced by older database drivers!

Comment: What's the difference between mysqli stored procedures than executing a query?

Comment: I didn't say stored procedures, I said **[prepared statements](http://il.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)**

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, soo that's their differences? is it highly recommended to use prepared statements? why?

Comment: It is **extermely** recommended to use prepared statements. It gives you a performance boost when executing multiple queries in a batch, and it also automatically escapes any variables you input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the username is not quoted.

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '{$username}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if your query was successful hence `$result` could actually contain FALSE.